# search inside child Array of objects - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, search

Currently i have below Array of Objects

```
obj = [
    {
        "id":28,
        cities: [
            {
                cityTypes: "AA",
                citySource: "sdsf"
            },
            {
                cityTypes: "BB",
                citySource: "sdsgf"
            },
            {
                cityTypes: "CC",
                citySource: "fgsdfgd"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id":56,
        cities: [
            {
                cityTypes: "DD",
                citySource: "sdsf"
            },
            {
                cityTypes: "EE",
                citySource: "sdsgf"
            },
            {
                cityTypes: "FF",
                citySource: "fgsdfgd"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "id":89,
        cities: [
            {
                cityTypes: "GG",
                citySource: "sdsf"
            },
            {
                cityTypes: "HH",
                citySource: "sdsgf"
            },
            {
                cityTypes: "II",
                citySource: "fgsdfgd"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to search `cityTypes` of specific value is present in the whole `Object`.

For suppose, i need to search `cityTypes = BB`

If `BB` is present in the whole object, return true

If `BB` is not preset, return `false`.

This is what i have tried, which does not seem to work.

```
for(let k=0; k<obj.length; k++){
    if(obj[k].cities){
        let cityObj = obj[k].cities;
        for(let city in cityObj){
            city.cityTypes !== "BB" ? "true" : "false"
        }
    }
}
```

What is the proper way to achieive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a `.some` inside another `.some`:

```js
const obj=[{"id":28,cities:[{cityTypes:"AA",citySource:"sdsf"},{cityTypes:"BB",citySource:"sdsgf"},{cityTypes:"CC",citySource:"fgsdfgd"}]},{"id":56,cities:[{cityTypes:"DD",citySource:"sdsf"},{cityTypes:"EE",citySource:"sdsgf"},{cityTypes:"FF",citySource:"fgsdfgd"}]},{"id":89,cities:[{cityTypes:"GG",citySource:"sdsf"},{cityTypes:"HH",citySource:"sdsgf"},{cityTypes:"II",citySource:"fgsdfgd"}]}];

console.log(
  obj.some(({ cities }) => cities.some(({ cityTypes }) => cityTypes === 'BB'))
);
console.log(
  obj.some(({ cities }) => cities.some(({ cityTypes }) => cityTypes === 'foobar'))
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code do not work because of several reason:

1. You need to do `let city of cityObj` since you are accessing property of `city` as `city.cityTypes` inside the inner loop so using `of` will give you each object in `city` variable.
2. You need to actually check if the match is found or not using a `if` condition. If a match is found with the `cityTypes` you expect then `break` the inner loop. Also `break` the outer loop if the match is found.

```js
var obj = [{
    "id": 28,
    cities: [{
        cityTypes: "AA",
        citySource: "sdsf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "BB",
        citySource: "sdsgf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "CC",
        citySource: "fgsdfgd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 56,
    cities: [{
        cityTypes: "DD",
        citySource: "sdsf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "EE",
        citySource: "sdsgf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "FF",
        citySource: "fgsdfgd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 89,
    cities: [{
        cityTypes: "GG",
        citySource: "sdsf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "HH",
        citySource: "sdsgf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "II",
        citySource: "fgsdfgd"
      }
    ]
  }
]
var found = false;
for (let k = 0; k < obj.length; k++) {
  if (obj[k].cities) {
    let cityObj = obj[k].cities;
    for (let city of cityObj) {
      found = city.cityTypes === "BB";
      if (found) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if (found) {
    break;
  }
}
console.log(found);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a double reduce should work

```js
var obj = [{
    "id": 28,
    cities: [{
        cityTypes: "AA",
        citySource: "sdsf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "BB",
        citySource: "sdsgf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "CC",
        citySource: "fgsdfgd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 56,
    cities: [{
        cityTypes: "DD",
        citySource: "sdsf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "EE",
        citySource: "sdsgf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "FF",
        citySource: "fgsdfgd"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 89,
    cities: [{
        cityTypes: "GG",
        citySource: "sdsf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "HH",
        citySource: "sdsgf"
      },
      {
        cityTypes: "II",
        citySource: "fgsdfgd"
      }
    ]
  }
]
var cityTypes1 = 'BB';
console.log(obj.reduce((total, cur) => 
    total||cur.cities.reduce((total, cur) => 
        total||cur.cityTypes === cityTypes1, false), 
    false))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var filtered = obj.filter((o) => {
    var found=false;
    for(let i=0;  i<o.cities.length; i++) {
        let city = o.cities[i];
        if(city.cityTypes === "BB"){
            found=true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return found;
})
console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

This short method returns true if at least one of city has required type:

```
function findMyCode(code) {
   return obj.some((d) => {
       return d.cities.some((city) => {
           return city.cityTypes === code;
       });
   });
}
```

Or you can try use [lodash](https://lodash.com/) library.

So you can use it:

```
var hasType = findMyCode('BB'); // returns true/false
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try with below code.

```
var result = false;
for(let k=0; k<obj.length; k++){
    if(obj[k].cities){
        let cityObj = obj[k].cities;
        for(let city in cityObj){
            if(cityObj[city].cityTypes == "BB"){
                result = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

return result or print console log.